# How to loop through only li elements inside a ul

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Xpath of ul element:

```
resultSet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@id='abc']/ul")
```

How to loop through only li elements inside a ul, given above ul element xpath?

Comment: Can you update the Question with your code trials & relevant HTML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for `li` nodes starting from already defined `ul` with below code:

```
resultSet = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@id='abc']/ul")
options = resultSet.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

To loop through list of `li` nodes simply do

```
for option in options:
    print(option.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a HTML like this:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Than iterating through `li` item in `ul` goes  like this:

```
  ulClass= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.someclass')

    if ulClass !=None:
        for li in ulClass.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul'):
            print(li.text)
```